# PHP problem writing consecutive single quotes?

Tags: php, string, file-io

I can't manage to write consecutive single-quotes on my server; This simple script output's only a single quote to the file:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('testWriteDoubleSingleQuote.dat', 'wb');
    fwrite($handle, "''");  //  only writes ' ONCE!
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

I've tried the pack() function as well, with the same result:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('testWriteDoubleSingleQuote.dat', 'wb');
    fwrite($handle, pack('nnn', 0x6061, 0x6127, 0x2763));  //  only writes 0x27 ONCE!
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Is this normal?  Something to do with magicquotes?

Comment: `fwrite($handle, "\'\'")`, perhaps, in case it's some weird windows-side parsing error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try four? `fwrite($handle, "''''");`

Comment: Yep - it writes two!  Seems like it's just replacing every instance of two consecutive ones with single ones??

Comment: Not sure what is the criteria, but it usually works in other contexts. You will need to preprocess your string and duplicate your single quotes.

Comment: Yuck.  That'd be tricky, because we deploy this on two separate servers, and PHP is only displaying this behavior on ONE of them.  :-(

Comment: @loneboat That is weird.  Maybe it's an OS issue because I'm running Windows and doing a `fwrite($handle, "''")` writes two quotes for me.

Comment: The two servers are on different OS's (Win Server 2003 32-bit vs. Win Server 2008 64-bit); Thanks for the input!  Hoping someone else can chime in who's more familiar with PHP/OS differences than I am...

Comment: @loneboat This probably won't make a difference, but try using single quotes to enclose the string: `fwrite($handle, '\'\'')`